# Web application showing miss alignment in IE 8

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an web application using asp.net and it almost completed.My application working properly in IE 7 but its not working properly in IE 8.It shoes an miss alignment of controls...

Comment: can you post some codes? so we can see the problem

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE9" />
       </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer> i have added this in my web config and its working as expected in local.But when i deploy this in IIS6 it is not working.